# Can't get the header for pages on WordPress child theme for Twenty Seventeen Theme to work

Tags: wordpress, image, header

I created a child theme for the Twenty Seventeen theme on WordPress. I added a video to the front page header that I'm trying to keep on it. However, I am trying to change the header of every other page to a height of 400px, a width that adjusts to cover the max-width of any monitor or browser, and I want to add text that is centered in the header (in front of the image) that will show the title of the page.

So far, I have changed the header tag in header.php from:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">

    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/header', 'image' ); ?>

    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'top' ) ) : ?>
        <div class="navigation-top">
            <div class="wrap">
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation/navigation', 'top' ); ?>
            </div><!-- .wrap -->
        </div><!-- .navigation-top -->
    <?php endif; ?>

</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

to:

```
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( is_single() || ( is_home() || ( is_page() && ! twentyseventeen_is_frontpage() ) ) ) ) : ?>
    <span class="has-header-image twentyseventeen-front-page home">
      <div id="page-header" class="custom-header">
        <div id="custom-header-media" class="custom-header-media" >
          <div id="wp-custom-header" class="wp-custom-header">
            <?php if ( is_home() && ! twentyseventeen_is_frontpage() ) {
              $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
              echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page_for_posts );
            } else {
              the_post_thumbnail( 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' );
            } ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="site-branding">
          <div class="wrap">
            <div class="site-branding-text">
              <h1 class="site-title">
                <?php if ( is_home() && ! twentyseventeen_is_frontpage() ) {
                  $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
                  echo get_the_title( $page_for_posts );
                } else {
                  the_title();;
                } ?>
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#content" class="menu-scroll-down"><?php echo twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-right' ) ); ?><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Scroll down to content', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></span></a>
      </div>
    </span>
  <?php else : get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/header', 'image' ); endif;?>

  <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'top' ) ) : ?>
    <div class="navigation-top">
      <div class="wrap">
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation/navigation', 'top' ); ?>
      </div><!-- .wrap -->
    </div><!-- .navigation-top -->
  <?php endif; ?>

</header>
```

This changed my featured image to the header image at it's full dimensions on every page, but the front page. However, I cannot figure out how to make the image's width adjust to every screen and/or browsers max width, nor can I figure out how to add text in front of the image. I don't want to just add the text to into the image itself using something like Photoshop or pixlr because then search engines won't pick it up. Can anyone tell me how I might go about achieving those two things? Is it even possible to do these if I am pulling my header from the featured image?

For reference on what I'm trying to achieve:

This is [my site](http://isupplementthis.com/contact/) currently *Note: My page will have "CONTACT" in the header image, and I will make the current title that lies below the header transparent as I don't believe there is a way to completely remove it on WordPress

And the header image on [this page](https://www.anabolicmen.com/moringa-testosterone/) is what I'm trying to achieve